# Error on model sanitize_forbidden_attributes rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am upgrading old rails 2 app to rails 4. There are some code written in the model for creating like

```
create(activated: true, sita_code: MULTIPROPERTY.downcase,
                    access_list: MULTIPROPERTY.downcase)
```

> I know we add permit parameters on controllers but I am getting this issue on model. How can I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are working with Rails < 4.2, you might need to declare all the attributes under the corresponding model. So for about answer will be

```
attr_accessible :activated, :sita_code, :access_list
```